SQL like query contains only a specific character
I'm trying to get records from SQL server starting with abc_ followed by at least one letter (a-z, A-Z) and then continue to the end with just letters and numbers (a-z, A-Z, 0-9). No special characters like . , ; _ ? -
I am using javax.persistence.Query to get result from dao so i prefer use some like as condition. But mostly I am tring to find paternt to SQL query. I think thats not regex language
Java implementation
public List<UserExport> getUserExport() {
        Query query = userExportDao.createQuery("SELECT c FROM UserExport c WHERE c.objectId LIKE :value").setParameter("value", "abc_[a-z,A-Z]%");
        return query.getResultList();
    }

objectId is varchar(255), primary key, not null
Match
abc_KlimD
ABC_PackoL
abc_novo65ny
abc_abcd
abc_abc1

Do not match
abc_ola_old
aBC_12615
abc_6novotny
abc_abc_
abc_ab_d

SELECT @@version
Microsoft SQL Server 2022


You're mixing in a regex character class (which moreover includes a comma, which you said you wanted to exclude). Is that valid?

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

To match the underscore in the LIKE expression, it needs to be escaped (e.g. abc[_][a-z,A-Z]%)

This should match all the requirements as a singular affirmative test:
c.objectId like 'abc[_][a-zA-Z]' + replicate('[a-zA-Z0-9]', len(c.objectId) - 5)

If you don't like the variable-length pattern created on the fly then maybe match on the prefix and then reject the ones with bad characters after the initial five characters:
c.objectId like 'abc[_][a-zA-Z]%' and c.objectId not like '_____%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'

https://dbfiddle.uk/NalRA0rO

2th: Give me 0 matches for some reason..
1st: I do not understand why, but it gives me different count of matches vs select as my solution down. Your matches less and i dont see paternt
(511 rows affected)
(556 rows affected)
For example abc_boguschoval and and_werichovam do not match for me with your solution.

@AdamNovotny It might be a trailing whitespace issue. As you saw in the linked fiddle all your examples line up. But without more details I can't offer much else at this point.

I found a solution for my problem, but it's more complicated than I expected
The REGEXP operation is not supported on Microsoft SQL Server 2022 and LIKE alone is not strong enough.
Use LIKE and NOT LIKE
SELECT count(*)
FROM USER_EXPORT
WHERE objectId LIKE 'abc_[A-Za-z]%' 
AND objectId NOT LIKE 'abc_[A-Za-z]%[^A-Za-z0-9]%';

Use LIKE and PATINDEX
SELECT count(*)
FROM USER_EXPORT
WHERE objectId LIKE 'abc_[A-Za-z]%'
AND PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z0-9]%', SUBSTRING(objectId, 5, LEN(objectId))) = 0;

SELECT count(*)
FROM USER_EXPORT
WHERE objectId LIKE 'abc_[A-Za-z]%'
AND PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z0-9]%', RIGHT(objectId, LEN(objectId) - 4)) = 0;

SELECT count(*)
FROM USER_EXPORT
WHERE objectId LIKE 'abc_[A-Za-z]%'
AND PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z0-9]%', STUFF(objectId, 1, 4, '')) = 0;

Solution in Java
public List<UserExport> getUserExport() {
        Query query = userExportDao.createQuery("SELECT c FROM UserExport c WHERE c.objectId LIKE :value1 AND objectId NOT LIKE :value2")
                .setParameter("value1", "abc_[a-z,A-Z]%")
                .setParameter("value2", "abc_[A-Za-z]%[^A-Za-z0-9]%");

        return query.getResultList();
    }

